# OutOfBoundsException into stack

Tags: java, stack, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException it is always appears in my program. How I can go into try{}?

```
@Override
    public Object pop() {
        if (stackIsEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("underflow");
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                Object temp = stack[top];
                stack[top--] = null;
                System.out.println("top is " + top);
                return temp;
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return "exception";
            }
        }
    }
```

added code of the rest class( I have the comparison with -1 into stackisEmpty()):

```
public class ArrayStackImpl implements ArrayStack {
    private int top = -1;
    private int maxLength;
    public Object stack[] = new Object[maxLength];

    public ArrayStackImpl(int maxLength) {
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stackIsEmpty() {
        return (top < 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void push(Object o) {
        if ((top >= maxLength - 1))
            System.err.println("overflow");
        else
            try {
                stack[++top] = o;
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            }
    }
```

Comment: I have a feeling that `top` is -1. Classic error when implementing stack.

Comment: You should include the entire class. In particular the constructor, the initialization of `top` and `stack` and the `push` method.

Comment: and if i will do it 0, it won't change. I tried

Comment: Side note: **Don't** catch an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. If an array index goes out of bounds it means that the program has a serious bug. Solve it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On popping of a non-empty stack `top` might become -1 (for "empty stack"). So

```
private int top = -1;

public boolean stackIsEmpty() {
    return top < 0; // != -1
}
```

---

Do the field initialisation in your constructor. Before that maxlength is not initialized, and 0.
Furthermore you do not need maxlength as field. `stack.length == maxlength`.

```
public Object[] stack; 

public ArrayStackImpl(int maxLength) {
    stack = new Object[maxLength];
```

*(I used the more conventional notation `Object[]`.)*

Comment: `return (top == 0) && (top == -1);` always yields false; `||` would be wrong too: a "hack" repair.

Comment: sorry i forgot change it there.. And I also have last problem

Comment: Your code above still does `stack = new Object[0];` which makes an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds inevitable. I made some changes to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check top is initialized to -1. Don't catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, find out why. Also, your stackIsEmpty should check if top equals -1.